# how to make an ios app adaptive in Xcode 6.1(objective C) using auto layouts or any other simple approach

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

I am very new to Xcode and so as with auto layouts and i want to make my app which i've created, adaptive in a very easy way. I have seen lots of tutorials on internet but nothing helped me with my app. so i don't know how to make my app adaptive. so i need a help.
           I have made an app that generate report in second view controller after providing inputs in first view controller.so i need to see how can i use auto layouts in my respective app to make it adaptive or there any easy way to get the results. i have seen all the videos related to it. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you've already worked through all the existing tutorials and watched Apples WWDC videos on this subject?

Comment: Are you asking whole code about this

Comment: Please elaborate your question... Are you looking for how to use auto layout ??

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Auto Layout and Size Classes. This way your app will work with all iPhone sizes and all iPads. It will also behave correctly in portrait and landscape.

For more details, you will need to read and watch a lot of documentations/WWDC videos.